# How to use LogisticRegression on categorical data?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

trans = pd.read_csv("steam3.csv")
dummies = pd.get_dummies(trans["platforms"],prefix="platforms")
trans = trans.join(dummies)
y = trans["c.owners"]
x = trans["platforms"]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

mymodel=linear_model.LogisticRegression()
mymodel.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

This is what [x looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYIYB.png).

This code returns an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbE9X.png) in line 21.

> ValueError: Could not convert string to float: 'windows'

Comment: Logistic regression is unable to work with non-numeric features so you need to convert (encode) them somehow e.g. one-hot encoding.

Comment: @MustafaAydın i have converted but still same error could not convert string to float: 'windows'

Comment: that means you didn't convert :) How did you do that conversion?

Comment: @MustafaAydındummies=pd.get_dummies(trans["platforms"],prefix="platforms")
dummies
trans=trans.join(dummies)

Comment: Please read [how to provide an MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question to include all the necessary information.

Comment: @MustafaAydın there converted result is incorrect  platforms_linux  ...  platforms_windows;mac;linux
0                    0  ...                            0
1                    0  ...                            0
2                    0  ...                            1
3                    0  ...                            0

Comment: @MustafaAydın may i know whats wrong with my data converting?

Comment: @dgdrrg print the `x` that you are giving to the `train_test_split` and please add it to the question with proper formatting (if you are unsure of the formatting, add an image of it).

Comment: @dgdrrg ..and please provide the full traceback of the error you are getting, and crop the parts of the code that after it since they are not reachable anyway..

Comment: @MustafaAydın i have added two images for that pls take a look

Comment: It says *dtype = object*, does this tell you something?

Comment: @Frightera sorry i dont get it

Comment: @dgdrrg Your data needs cleaning, you have an entry like `"windows;mac"`. You need to decide how to evaluate it (e.g. windows or mac?), then call `pd.get_dummies(cleaned_x, drop_first=True)` and pass it to `train_test_split` etc. (for `drop_first`, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414806/clear-explanation-of-dummy-variable-trap/414813).)

Comment: @MustafaAydın sorry i don't get it . what should I do if I want to have the platforms value windows;mac;linux  and windows

Comment: @dgdrrg Then, after `x=trans["platforms"]`, write `x = pd.get_dummies(x, drop_first=True)` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The column `platforms` is still stored as `dtype: object`. You can see `x` is still printing out as 'windows', 'windows;mac;linux', etc.

You tried `pd.get_dummies()` and after doing so, you went back to `x = trans['platforms']`, which is the original text column!

Try this:

```py
# Read data
trans = pd.read_csv("steam3.csv")

# Turn `platforms` into dummy variables
x = pd.get_dummies(trans['platforms'], drop_first=True, prefix='platform')

# Split data
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# Declare and fit model
mymodel=linear_model.LogisticRegression()
mymodel.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

This will drop `platforms` and replace it with multiple dummy columns. You can now fit your logistic regression on these columns.

Note: I took the liberty of using `drop_first=True` in order to avoid multicollinearity.

Comment: may i have the code please?mine still doesn't work

Comment: I added some code. Please let me know if it worked.